# Show that $\int_{0}^{1}x^pdx$ converges for $p>-1$ and diverges otherwise.

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Show that $\int_{0}^{1}x^pdx$ converges for $p>-1$ and diverges otherwise.

---

I know how to show that this integral converges for values less than one and diverges for all others, but the question that I've posted seems to say the opposite.

So my question is can I show this the same way that I should show that it converges, or could this have been a typo on my professor's part? I'm not sure why it's -1 instead of 1.  Am I missing something obvious? Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: look at the behavior of the integrand as it approaches the lower limit of integration (the function will go undefined at 0 for p <= -1). can you use improper integration to solve this?

Comment: @costrom Would it be acceptable for me to say that the integral in the problem above is equivalent to $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{-p}dx$$ for p <1? I ask because I know that this converges for  p<1 and diverges otherwise, but would it be wrong to consider them equivalent?

Comment: those are equivalent statements, sure, but you still need to prove *why* it diverges (using the limit of the function as it approaches zero)

Comment: You are accustomed to the $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^p}$ version. Make the change of variable $y=1/x$.  Or else work directly with the definition, calculate $\int_{\epsilon}^1 x^p\,dx$, and let $\epsilon\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equivalent statement: Show that $\int_{0}^{1}x^{-p}dx$ converges for $p<1$ and diverges otherwise.

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{-p}dx=\lim_{c\to0}\int_{c}^{1}x^{-p}dx$$

If p<1 then: $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{-p}dx=\lim_{c\to0}\frac{1}{1-p}(1-c^{1-p})=\frac{1}{1-p}$$ 
We see that for p <1 it converges.

If p=1 then: $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{-p}dx=\lim_{c\to0}-\ln(c)=+\infty$$
Thus for p = 1 it diverges.

If p>1 then: $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{-p}dx=\lim_{c\to0}\frac{1}{1-p}(1-c^{1-p})=+\infty$$
So for p>1 it diverges.

Therefore, since the statements are equivalent $\int_{0}^{1}x^{-p}dx$ converges for p> -1 and diverges otherwise.